# zap proxy url for remediation?

Tags: owasp, zap

running OWASP Zap proxy and i get output like:

```
WARN-NEW: Cookie Without Secure Flag [10011]
```

Is there a db or wiki of remediation approaches that take the issue ID?  I'm looking for a way to humanize the results, with a message like "See http://how_to?issue=10011"

Thanks for any help,
KEvin

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are using one of the packages ZAP scans, eg the baseline?
If so rerun your scan using one of the reporting options, eg '-r report_html' - this will give you a lot more information.

Comment: Thanks Simon.  I am running this in a docker container and I get A file based option has been specified but the directory '/zap/wrk' is not mounted